# How can I slice this dataset

Tags: r

I would like to slice results in its x, y components for each row, the same as I slice dat

that is, I would like to isolate each column [,1][,2][,..] and split it the same as dat so that my code splits the test_index correctly. splitting it by the size of the actually data set and not by the size of dat, which is 100.

here is the layout of results and dat.

```
> results
  [,1]        [,2]        [,3]         [,4]         [,5]
x Numeric,100 Numeric,500 Numeric,1000 Numeric,5000 Numeric,10000
y Numeric,100 Numeric,500 Numeric,1000 Numeric,5000 Numeric,10000
```

```
> dat
           x        y
1   68.30298 66.44188
2   69.41395 69.54029
3   68.19536 65.46259
4   72.90762 73.38170
5   70.83796 68.87421
6   64.21743 69.51929
7   69.19132 71.34144
```

and here is the code I'm using

```
n <- c(100,500,1000,5000,10000)
Sigma <- 9*matrix(c(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0), 2, 2)
dat <- MASS::mvrnorm( 100, c(69, 69), Sigma) %>%
        data.frame() %>% setNames(c("x", "y"))
dat

set.seed(1, sample.kind="Rounding")

training <- function(y) {
    rmse<-replicate(100,{test_index <- createDataPartition(y, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)
        train_set = dat %>% slice(-test_index)
        test_set = dat %>% slice(test_index)
        fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = train_set)
        y_hat <- fit$coef[1] + fit$coef[2]*test_set$x
        sqrt(mean((y_hat - test_set$y)^2))
        })
    structure(c(mean(rmse),sd(rmse)),names=c("mean","sd"))
}

df<-c(n,mean(n),sd(n))
set.seed(1, sample.kind="Rounding")
results<-sapply(n,function(n){
    Sigma<- 9*matrix(c(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0), 2, 2)
    dat<- MASS::mvrnorm(n, c(69,69), Sigma) %>%
    data.frame() %>%
    setNames(c("x","y"))
    
    })

y<-results[2,]
results

set.seed(1, sample.kind="Rounding")
results<- map(y,training)
results
```

Comment: I in the `replicate` you may need `simplify = FALSE`

Comment: that hasn't seemed to do much, it still returns the error

```Error in UseMethod("slice_") :
  no applicable method for 'slice_' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'list')"
```

Comment: I didn't test that.  sorry

Comment: No don't worry I appreciate the help regardless

Answer (score 2):

```
dat1<-do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, x=results[,1]$x, y=results[,1]$y))
```

I have done it really hacky and essentially made a single data set for each column

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is to place the replicator within the sapply, this will take away the need to slice the data set and is shown here

```
results <- sapply(n, function(n){
    Sigma <- 9*matrix(c(1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0), 2, 2)
    dat <- MASS::mvrnorm(n, c(69, 69), Sigma) %>%
        data.frame() %>% setNames(c("x", "y"))
    rmse <- replicate(100, {
        test_index <- createDataPartition(dat$y, times = 1, p = 0.5, list = FALSE)
        train_set <- dat %>% slice(-test_index)
        test_set <- dat %>% slice(test_index)
        fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = train_set)
        y_hat <- predict(fit, newdata = test_set)
        sqrt(mean((y_hat-test_set$y)^2))
```